# GWT TypeOracle.getTypes does not return all types

Tags: java, gwt, types, code-generation

I have a custom generator that generates code only for somes classes in my project. The following code is at the beginning of the `generate` method, and puts all the classes I will need to work on in the `clazzes` list

```
TypeOracle oracle = context.getTypeOracle();
JClassType markerInterfaceType = oracle.findType(MY_PARENT_CLASS.class.getName());
List<JClassType> clazzes = new ArrayList<JClassType>();
for (JClassType classType : oracle.getTypes()) {
  if (!classType.equals(markerInterfaceType)
      && classType.isAssignableTo(markerInterfaceType)) {
    clazzes.add(classType);
  }
}
```

This code has been unchanged for more than a year, but since last week it seems that a few classes are not taken into account by the generator.

After some digging, i found that those classes are not even in the list returned by `oracle.getTypes()`

- Those ignored classes are not newly created classes (some were left unchanged for several month)
- As far as i can tell, there is no way to differenciate a class that will be ignored from any other class
- No upgrade in our gwt version was made (some of us are using 2.5.0, others 2.5.1)
- No upgrade in packages used by those classes either
- `oracle.findType(MISSING_CLASS.class.getName())` returns `null`
- the problem appears only for some people, but not on the same classes
- renaming problematic classes seems to correct the problem

My best guess would be that i have a cache problem somewhere, but i have no idea where to look.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the contents of gwt-UnitCache folder? It more often than not helps fixing seemingly strange errors like this for me.
Also, do you have some example names of the missing classes? As renaming them helps, next to a caching related issue this might as well be name related.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late for the answer but I was facing this issue for the last 3 days. No amount of clearing gwt-UnitCache folder was helping. Finally found the problem. The class which was not getting picked up by oracle had a reference of a gwt-ext class and I had not inherited gwt-ext in my module definition(.gwt.xml file). Removing that reference fixed the problem. So, using anything in your class which might not be referenced in your module definition or is not part of  can cause your class not getting picked up by Oracle. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Tielemans stated in his comment, delete your gwt-UnitCache directory (should be at the root of your project if you're using Eclipse) and rebuild. That should correct the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

T**he missing class doesn't compile right and that silently fails. A typical cause is super sources**, because otherwise the normal java compilation would have already failed compilation.

[This question asks how to figure out what line is actually failing silently inside that missing class.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674908/gwt-rebinder-typeoracle-gettypefoo-foo-returns-null-how-to-get-the-real-er)

Comment: Isn't that basically what @anand-saha was already saying? (though could be reworded / improved)

Comment: yes. That answer blames a missing inherit statement - which could be the cause too, instead of a super source. And there's probably a dozen other potential causes why that class doesn't compile right.