# GWT rebinder: TypeOracle.getType("foo.Foo") returns null: how to get the real error?

Tags: gwt

I have a class Foo:

```
package foo;
import bar.Bar; // Bar is super-sourced badly
public class Foo {
    private Bar b = new Bar(); // no-arg constructor of Bar doesn't exist
    ...
}
```

When I have a rebind that does:

```
JClassType t = TypeOrace.getType("foo.Foo"); // return null
```

That returns null, even though "foo.Foo" exists. The real problem is that Bar line inside `Foo.java`. **Is there anyway to get the real error instead of null?** So something that contains the word `Bar` or the line `private Bar b = new Bar();` or a line number?

Comment: Does `-failOnError` (or it's `-strict` alias) help?

Comment: Yes, it's in there:
`[ERROR] Line 17: The method parse(CharSequence) in the type LocalDateTime is not applicable for the arguments (String, DateTimeFormatter)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by tbroyer as a comment.

Configure the `gwt-maven-plugin` to `failOnError`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And one of the errors in the output list will explain the problem.